# Run own function in pymongo in aggregation pipeline

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a function

```
distanceFromGPS(latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2):
latitude2=float(latitude2)
longitude2=float(longitude2)
R = 6371
dLat = math.radians(latitude2-latitude1)
dLon = math.radians(longitude2-longitude1)
a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + math.sin(dLon/2) * math.sin(dLon/2) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude1)) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude2))
c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
d = R * c
return d
latitude1 = 1.0
longitude1 = 1.0
```

I want to run this function in aggregation pipeline

```
cursor = collection.aggregate(
   [
     {"$match":{"Time":{"$gte" : datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 4)}}},
     {"$group":{"_id": "$Name", "LatLong": {"$cond": [ { "$lte":[distanceFromGPS(latitude1,longitude1,"$Latitude","$Longitude"), 2]}, {"$addToSet": {"Lat":"$Latitude","Long":"$Longitude" }},  ]}}},
     {"$project": { "Name":"$_id","LatLong":1,"_id":0,"Count": { "$size":"$LatLong" }}},
     {"$sort":{"Count":-1}}  
   ]
)
```

I get an error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: $Latitude

How can I do this? The Latitude and Longitude fields are both float type.

Comment: It seems to be doing the function, your input is bad. Read the error, it says that `$Latitude` can't be converted to a float- what is `$Latitude` as it comes in? Python is telling you it isn't a number it can figure out.

Comment: Latitude in the mongodb is of string type.It is a floating point number though e.g. "52.678" which is why I have latitude2=float(latitude2)
longitude2=float(longitude2) in the beginning of my function. Can you please suggest something?

Comment: The function is getting the literal string `"$Latitude"`, which it cannot convert into a float- you call the function as `distanceFromGPS(latitude1, longitude1, "$Latitude", "$Longitude")`, lat/long1 are both variable references, but the other two you are passing the literal string into the function. You may be able to fix it by wrapping a lambda- as is, Python will execute that before ever handing it into `aggregate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: After reading all the docs twice, I've come to the conclusion that you can't. You may have to re-write your function using mongo's [aggregation pipeline operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-expression-operators) to get the proper effect.

Comment: I have now converted Latitude and Longitude to float on the database. Now is there a way of doing it? I still get the error.

Comment: mongodb's aggregate framework cannot handle attempts to call a python function inside the aggregate call- it can only handle mongo-specific pipeline operators, as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: I thought so on reading the docs. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Outside of leaving the mongo framework and/or extending the source yourself? Not likely- the math is too complex for the pipeline ops, and I don't believe aggregates take kindly to attempts to mash them up later (i.e. just storing the data of `$Lat` and `$Long` in your aggregate, and replacing them after collection via your function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $function operator to define a custom function and apply it to each document. But you will have to write it in JavaScript.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/

Comment: Thanks for you contribution. However, this is a Comment, or a link-only response, as per SO guidelines. You can read more in the help section StackOverflow.com/help.